# Using Conditional Compilation Symbols across two projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, projects-and-solutions

Let's start with some details:

I'm working with Visual Studio 2010 Express. I have 2 separate projects under one solution. The first project is the main game and contains all the source files. The second is a level editor that uses the game's source files but starts from a different class, starting the level editor. Both projects have different namespaces

The level editor has a project reference to the game and depends on it; as such, the game builds before the level editor when compiling. What I want to do is add a conditional compilation symbol called "LEVELEDITOR" in the level editor project so I can use it for specific level editor features.

The problem is that I simply cannot get the game to recognize the LEVELEDITOR symbol even though I defined it in the level editor's project build settings. I went as far as creating a new library, adding references to the library in both projects, and then adding the symbol to the level editor class but even that failed as the library was not able to recognize the symbol.

I looked at Universal Apps to see how they did things, and I found that they have essentially the same project structure as me but have some inner workings that allow the symbols to work.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone can help with this issue. I can work around the symbols, but it wouldn't be as nice and convenient as just using the symbols themselves. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - it sounds like you expect the game project to be aware of a symbol you defined for the level editor project. That's simply not going to work - it's a compile-time only symbol, which only affects the project you're compiling. Can you show us what you're trying to do in code?

Comment: @Jon Skeet I'm trying to achieve something along the lines of this:


#if LEVELEDITOR
//Do stuff
#endif

I expect the code above to run only if I'm in the level editor and not when in the game. In the level editor I use the game's objects, and there are things I want to do to them only in the level editor.

Comment: No, that won't work. Bear in mind that the game code doesn't get recompiled - it's running the same code either way. It sounds like you should basically have some execution-time context so the code "knows" whether or not you're running in the level editor.